ENOENT[undefined] Execution returned code=-4058 in 0.01 seconds
Ok, so I tried the Manim sideview extention for vscode, and even though I have the path (the path to the manim installation in the env), and the manim version correct, I still have code = -4058.
And here's the exact: ENOENT[undefined] Execution returned code=-4058 in 0.01 seconds
I tried setting the manim path, but that's no help. And I tried setting the manim version, but to no avail.
